# I want to copy the content of my first activity (i.e the java code ) to my fragment on the click of a button

Tags: java, android

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM1D1.png) is My activity on which there is a button (Source Code) and i want if i click on that button then it should paste all the content(i.e java code of the activity) to my fragment

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98VBM.png) is my Fragment . I want to that my java code should be copied to java fragment and xml code should  copy to xml fragment Only when i click the Source Code Button on my activity.

This is my Activity Code

```
package com.example.shivnandan.listview;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class main_act extends Activity
{

    TextView t1 ,t2;
    EditText e1;
    Button b1,b2;
   // String e;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_act_layout);

       // e =( getIntent().getExtras().getString("main_act"));

        t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),main_act_2.class);
                i.putExtra("name",(e1.getText().toString()));
                startActivity(i);

            }


        });


b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(),SourceCode_Activity.class);

        startActivity(i);

    }

});
    }



}
```

This is My Fragment Activity

```
package com.example.shivnandan.listview;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ZoomControls;

public class Fragment1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    ZoomControls z;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, null);


        // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1,container,false);


        z = (ZoomControls) v.findViewById(R.id.zoomControls);
        final TextView tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        z.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                float x = tv1.getScaleX();
                float y = tv1.getScaleY();


                tv1.setScaleX((float) (x + 1));
                tv1.setScaleY((float) (y + 1));

            }
        });

        z.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                float x = tv1.getScaleX();
                float y = tv1.getScaleY();


                tv1.setScaleX((float) (x - 1));
                tv1.setScaleY((float) (y - 1));

            }
        });
return v;



    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to accomplish.  Copying source code doesn't make sense in the context of a running application.  If at runtime you want one thing to do the same operations as another thing, you reuse the first thing, you don't make a copy of the source code.

Comment: sir i am trying to make an offline app in which a user can see the java code and xml of the activity.

Comment: for example if they wish to see how scroll bar works then what i want is they can see the code and  layout code , when the click on the source code.

Comment: Perhaps put the code on git hub or some such and link to it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can just copy the source code like that.

One easy way of achieving it would be by defining the strings which are the source codes of whatever you want to display and setting them appropriately as text to a textview in your fragment based on the button clicked.